# How long does it takes to start receiving location updates after iOS device reboot?

Tags: ios, location, ibeacon, region-monitoring

I have an app that does geofencing/beacon region monitoring. The app functions well in -  foreground, background and killed state.

The problem: I have been noticing a delay in the beacon/geofence events(entry/exit) after I restart the phone(without killing the app) and do not launch the app manually upon restart. I only start getting the entry/exit events after 3-4 minutes of restart, even if I enter the region before.
Is it normal behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is normal.**  I have noticed this delay of several minutes since `CoreLocation` added iBeacon support in version 7.  The exact amount of time varies from one hardware model to the next, and even between reboots on the same hardware model.

While it might be possible to statistically characterize the delay with repeated tests, this is very time consuming to do.  In the end, there is nothing you can do about it anyway.

Comment: Thanks for coming back on this. I too reckon from the discussions that I have looked into that it is normal, but I cannot find any clear documentation around this specific delay... Specifically from Apple, which makes it rather difficult to convince any end client about this.

Comment: Agreed.  Unfortunately, this is a case where Apple's closed-source approach really bites app developers.  Because there is no way to prove to customers that it this behavior isn't a bug, or even determine exactly when the behavior can be expected.

Comment: Thanks. Another thing if you have any idea about? In the above case, I did not kill the app before restarting the device. In case, I kill it and then restart the device. What has been your experience for this scenario? I was expecting - NOT to receive any entry/exit events, as presumably OS will not automatically notify the app. BUT I receive sporadic and erratic entry events eg. like after 44 minutes post restart. Any thoughts?

Comment: I cannot explain that observation.  Killing the app should not affect detections after reboot.

Comment: While I agree have this stated out clearly in the specs, or at least having a consistent behavior would be great, I personally think developers slightly over-obsess over this one. Unless you have some very specific use case in mind which leads to the device being rebooted often, most iOS users only reboot during iOS updates.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. @heypiotr: I agree and I think most developers would too but it's more QA guys/customers who get fuzzed about this. Developers like us find ourself in a difficult spot due to the lack any proper documentation and consistent behaviour.